# How can I make a search part for wordpress site?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have a wordpress site which I want to make a search utility for it in menu.

I know if we put this to browser :

```
www.yoursite.com?s=keyword
```

It searches all posts for keyword in their title.

But I don't how to make the form and use Javascript to handle that.

Any ideas wil be helpful

What I have tried in header.php :

```
 <script>$(document).ready(function(){
 function search(){
     var uri =  $("#searchtxt").val();
     window.location.href="www.codepro.gq?s="+uri;
     return;
     }
 })
 </script>
```

In menu part :

```
 <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    <div>
      <input type="text"  id="searchtxt" placeholder="Search" />
    </div>
    <button  onclick="search()">Search</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Have you looked at any plugins? https://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use jQuery (I am an amateur)
I did it only with Javascript, edit it as you want.

Here's the Javascript & Form Code, I changed the url to "http", I don't know but there was a problem when I used "www" with the url

```js
  function search(){
     var uri =  document.getElementById("searchtxt");
     window.location.href = "http://www.codepro.gq?s="+uri.value;
     return;
     }
```

```html
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    <div>
       <input type="text"  id="searchtxt" placeholder="Search" />
    </div>
 <input type="button" value="Search" onClick="search()"/>
```

I changed the `<button>` tag to `<input>` tag as different browsers use different default types for the `<button>` element.